# Cordova/PhoneGap on iOS - minimum version?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an application developed using PhoneGap 2.3 that runs on Andriod, BBOS and iOS. I need to update the application but I cannot find any confirmation as to the minimum version of Cordova/PhoneGap that is required for iOS submission.

PhoneGap Build still offers 2.5 upward; is it fair to assume that 2.5 is therefore acceptable for an iOS application? Note that I am not actually using PhoneGap build for the iOS submission as I require a modified plist so I am building with XCode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

minimum version is 2.5 because it removed the UDID functions forbidden from apple on may